# What are the limitations of using SQLDelight in KMM (prod)

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

SQLDelight is still marked as experimental library on maven repository [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.sqldelight/runtime-jvm), though the first version seems to be released in October 2018.

I made a sample app in KMM where I'm able to insert/delete rows, and it seems to be working fine for our use case so far. But, can someone help me understand what aspects of it would not be safe for usage in prod. Are there any perf issues? Or is there any possibility of random crashes in prod? Or, do we know if there are apps which successfully use SqlDelight in Prod for their KMM applications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why that link describes sqldelight as experimental for multiplatform. Many apps currently ship with sqldelight on iOS.

I wrote the underlying driver (https://github.com/touchlab/SQLiter/) and work with team and community to maintain the sqldelight implementation.

There's nothing that I don't think is production ready. Performance had some sore spots, but there's been considerable attention paid to that recently. I haven't run many benchmarks but I would expect sqldelight to compare favorably to anything out there doing similar work.